# Direct assignment to the reverse side of a related set is prohibited. Use images.set() instead while using create()

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, drf-queryset

I am building a simple images blog app, And I build two models and one with `Parent ForeignKey`.

I made the `serializer` but when I try to create a new instance then it is keep showing me

> Direct assignment to the reverse side of a related set is prohibited. Use images.set() instead.

models.py

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)

class Image(models.Model):
    gallery = models.ForeignKey(Gallery, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="images")
    text = models.CharField(max_length=300)
```

serializer.py

```
class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = "__all__"

class GallerySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    images = ImageSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Gallery
        fields = "__all__"

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Gallery.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Then I also tried creating both model's instances separately.

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    new_data = Gallery.objects.create(poll=1, images=validated_data["images"])

    return new_data
```

But it also showed me the same error it showed me before.

**One more thing**, `validated_data` is not showing id when I use print

I am new in `Django-Rest-Framework`, I have tried many times but it is still not creating.

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you exactly what to do. Assuming `validated_data['images']` is an iterable of `Image` objects:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    new_data = Gallery.objects.create(poll=1)
    new_data.images.set(validated_data['images'])
    return new_data
```

Comment: It is showing `'Image' instance expected, got OrderedDict([('text', 'First Choice'), ('gallery', <Gallery: First Gallery>)])` now

Comment: When I print `validated_data['images']` then it is showing `[OrderedDict([('text', 'First Image'), ('gallery', <Gallery: First Gallery>)]), OrderedDict([('text', 'Second Image'), ('gallery', <Gallery: First Gallery>)]), OrderedDict([('text', 'Third Image'), ('gallery', <Gallery: First Gallery>)]), OrderedDict([('text', 'Fourth Image'), ('gallery', <Gallery: First Gallery>)])]`

Comment: `new_data.images.set` takes an iterable of `Image` objects, but `validated_data['images']` is a `list` of `OrderedDict` objects. You will either need to retrieve the `Image` object you need via the ORM.